# How to use tfjs-node with libtensorflow that is built from source

Tags: tensorflow, node-gyp, tensorflow.js

I see that it is possible to use `libtensorflow` that is built from source, as mentioned in the README
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node#optional-build-libtensorflow-from-tensorflow-source

I have successfully built from source, but I don't know how to let `tfjs-node` use this custom built version, instead of the pre-built one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the following workaround seems to work:

Copy the file `bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow.so` from the tensorflow source directory to replace `node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/deps/lib/libtensorflow.so` inside your project.

Hopefully there is a better way to do `npm install` such that there is no need to download the pre-compiled version.

Comment: I'm also interested in this, please of you found a solution share it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd manually re installed the libtensorflow c and it resolved the issue:

follow the instructions here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c#setup