# How to build tensorflowjs-node with bazel?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

When I run the program using the tensorflowjs node, the following message appears in the console:

> I tensorflow / core / platform / cpu_feature_guard.cc: 141] Your CPU supports the TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2

README talks about the possibility of building a library from sources using a bazel:

> bazel build --config=monolithic //tensorflow/tools/lib_package:libtensorflow

So I installed a bazel with Chocolatey:

> choco install bazel

After successful installation, I downloaded the code from the repository
(https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node), in the catalog I ran the command described above that's give me output:

> INFO: Options provided by the client:
>     Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=120
>   INFO: Options provided by the client:
>     'build' options: --python_path=C:/Python27/python.exe
>   ERROR: Config value monolithic is not defined in any .rc file
>   INFO: Invocation ID: bbe71a5c-1f35-42e1-bfb8-84f976598105

I was looking for a solution with .rc file, but I found nothing that could help me.

What am I doing wrong? do I download the wrong repository or run the command in the wrong place? Or maybe something wrong with Python on my machine?

bazel version: 0.22.0,
node version: 11.10.0,
python vesion: 2.7.15

Comment: Take a look at a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887109/how-to-use-tfjs-node-with-libtensorflow-that-is-built-from-source

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I found a mistake. You need to download this repository (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) instead of the tensorflow-node version and run the build command.